# How can I add a local library into my Leinigen project?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'd like to add a local library of utilities that I wrote to my project in Leinigen without having to make jars of the library, or without copying the code.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [checkouts](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies) feature of leiningen to add a symbolic link to the project directory containing the library.

```
cd project-dir # where the project.clj file is
mkdir checkouts
ln -s ~/library/project/dir/ checkouts/library-name
```

Then add a dependency to the project.clj file

EDIT: If your included code is not it's own project then perhaps including the source directly with git submodules is an option, though some would recommend making it a project that can have a version. It's also worth considering running `lein install` to build jars and put them in your local maven repo since it only takes two words. 
ps: i'm assuming your library is a clojure project.

Comment: Checkouts just uses the latest version of the source files. It doesn't let you depend on something that doesn't have a project.clj or a pom.

Comment: If you aren't going to build jars its a little hard to do much more. If a project has neither jars not a project file is it really a "library". In such cases perhaps git submodules would be a better option.

Comment: I agree; my answer to this question would be "you can't: you need to have more structure than just some loose .clj files".

Comment: I have worked on projects that use lose code in a submodule, and it was in no way "good" or easier than using a library. It was not worth it.

Comment: EuAndre, I have used checkouts, and it can be useful when testing new changes to your project, but I've found `lein install` to be easiest for most purposes, i.e. I agree with the other comments.  The only thing to know is that if you write your own pom.xml file, `lein install` will overwrite it; then you have to restore it, e.g. with `git stash` if you are using git.

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Suppose my project is called `my-lib`. So I made the link to the `my-lib` folder (I should link the folder, right?), and added `[my-lib "0.1.0"]` to my app dependency, but it says it can't find artifact in clojars, or on maven. Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you using checkout or "lein install". Could you perhaps post some or all of the project.clj files involved and the output from "ls -l" in the checkouts directory?

Comment: The `project.clj` file is [here](http://clojurepastebin.appspot.com/9949001) and the output from `ls -l` is [here](http://clojurepastebin.appspot.com/9959001). The app name is `programinha-do-andrezinho` and the lib name is `andrutilj`.